# Define Current Record in Rails Controller Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I am developing a model in a rails app that allows a user to associate records to one another in a child -> parent relationship similar to a basic user following model. I have based my controller methods on the code below.

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to user
end

def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
end
```

However, as the the active record that will act as the follower cannot be called similar to the current_user, I am having trouble adapting this part of the code. My current code is as follows:

```
def create
    record = Record.find(params[:parent_id])
    current_record = Record.find(params[:child_id])
    current_record.follow(record)
    redirect_to record
end

def destroy
    Record = Recordrelationship.find(params[:id]).parent
  current_record = Recordrelationship.find(params[:id]).child
    current_record.unfollow(record)
    redirect_to record
end
```

Currently I receive "Could not find record without an ID" error that is originating from this code. For reference, I have been using the this as the base for my model: https://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/following_users. Additional relevant code is below:

Routes

```
resources :records do
    member do
      get :children, :parents
    end
  end

  resources :recordrelationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Record Model

```
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Recordrelationship",
                                foreign_key: "child_id",
                                dependent: :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Recordrelationship",
                                 foreign_key: "parent_id",
                                 dependent: :destroy
has_many :children, through: :active_relationships, source: :parent
has_many :parents, through: :passive_relationships, source: :child

validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, uniqueness: true

def follow(other_record)
    children << other_record
end

def unfollow(other_record)
    children.delete(other_record)
end
```

Relationship Model

```
class Recordrelationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :child, class_name: "Record"
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Record"
    validates :child_id, presence: true
    validates :parent_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Judging from the error, I think either `params[:parent_id]` or `params[:child_id]` doesn't contain anything. Could you also provide the code of the form please.

Comment: '<%= form_for(@ingref.active_relationships.build) do |f| %>
     <div><%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, @ingref.id %></div>
     <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
<% end %>'

Comment: Ok, you're passing the parent id through a hidden field in the form, and the `child_id`? Is it nested in the url?

Comment: Yes, the url looks something like this: http://localhost:3000/record/3

Comment: Ok, this is not a nested route then, because following the rails convention this id in the url would just be named `id` not `child_id`... try to change that

Comment: It is still giving me the same error message, but it is definitely this line that is triggering the error.

Comment: Could you please also post the relevant routes - you can edit your question instead of posting it in the comments

Comment: You posted both `create` and `destroy` actions. Do both result in an exception or only one of the two?

Comment: Both result in an error. I believe they are both stemming from the same issue.